# Annoying spellchecking format

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word

I work from home producing transcripts that require the format of:

> question?---answer

*(with no spacing in between the words or the ?--- symbol)*

When I'm checking a document, it stops at each of these questions and takes a long time to spell check documents.

How can I get Word to bypass this `question?---answer` section?

Answer (score 2):

How about doing a search-replace of "?----" to "? "  and then once spellcheck is complete, reversing, replacing "? " with "?----"

Comment: Thanks for that.  I was hoping to find a way to bypass the whole question?---answer thing, but your tip will save me some time.  I hadn't thought of trying that.  Thanks again and I'll give it a go.